# How do I interpret this data return from a robot?

Tags: arrays, sensors

I'm trying to read a wall sensor on a robot. The description is:

> The strength of the wall sensor’s signal is returned as an 
>       unsigned 16-bit value, high byte first.
>
> Range: 0-4095

Any clues on how to interpret this? The data comes back to me in a byte array of size 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd interpret that to mean:

Range of values:

`0000 0000 0000 0000` to `0000 1111 1111 1111 1111`

Given the return type, you'll get:

`ARR[0] 0000 0000, ARR[1] 0000 0000` to `ARR[0] 0000 1111, ARR[1] 1111, 1111`

0 possibly means out of range, 4095 possibly means impact? Suck it and see!